# how can I use japanese pronouns if I am beginner in the language japanese?

Tags: expressions, pronouns

hello everyone I am very beginner in japanese just I have 2 day learning japanese then I am not expert in this language yet I saw in **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_pronouns)** this japanese pronouns:

1. watashi わたし
2. watakushi   わたくし

   there are more way but I think this first two are fundamental if I want to learn japanese.

   as say in its description from every expresion say this:

   in **watashi** say this:

> In formal or polite contexts, this is gender neutral; in casual speech, it is typically only used by women. Use by men in casual context may be perceived as either stiff or feminine.

I understand is only used by women but it is saying that : perceived as either 
   stiff or feminine?  then I can not say if I am man this  word is only for women in 
   informal way? or what?

in the second word say this :

> The most formal personal pronoun.

but in much book I see alway say that is more common say watashi?

my question is: what japanese pronouns should I use first if I am beginner A1 in tje language japanese.

I hope my question is not noob but I am new in this language and I try learn well this language I hope you opinion,suggents,critical,etc.

PST:Merry Christmas

Comment: Related: [Usage of 私 in Informal Situations](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39514/5010); [Is it ok for non-japanese to refer to themselves as 僕 and if not why?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/580/5010)  IMO you can just stick to *watashi* while you're a beginner. *Watakushi* is too formal.

Comment: if I a beginner should I use Watashi? but I will want to travel the next year to japan, should I continue using watashi there?

Comment: As an ordinary tourist, yes, *watashi* is always the safest choice. If you think you're going to master casual Japanese to the point where you can enjoy chatting with native speakers at izakaya, that's when you may want to consider *boku*.

Comment: "They are casual places for after-work drinking"?  izakaja?  I not drink I want to go japan,tokio  where could I use boku? so if I will plan sette down in japan should I use boku with friends and watashi with my boss?

Comment: Watakushi is _very polite_ (it's humble or honorific). Watashi is commonly used by both men and women. It's regarded as "more feminine" only because men also use "Ore" or "Boku" (in informal situations) when women do not.

Comment: then I should use watashi because it is the  way more use?